# localStorage.getItem() doesn't retrieve data on page refresh - ReactJs (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a to-do list app with ReactJs, working with `localStorage` the `setItem()` works fine but the `getItem()` doesn't return anything except empty array!

- I'm using `|| ""` because the `JSON.parse()` returns `string || null` in TypeScript.

```
useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
 }, [todos]);

 useEffect(() => {
   const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos") || "");
   if (items) {
     setTodos(items);
   }
 }, []);
```

Here's where i supply data to `todos`

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<todosObj[]>([]);
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
const [status, setStatus] = useState<"All" | "completed" | "uncompleted">(
    "All"
  );
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

const inputHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputText(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

const submitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCount(count + 1);

    if (inputText !== "") {
      setTodos([
        ...todos,
        {
          id: count,
          text: inputText,
          completed: false,
          date: date,
        },
      ]);
    }

    setInputText("");
  };
```

Comment: Please specify how you set the data for `todos` and what this data entails.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I dont have enough reputation to comment, so have to post it as an answer:

Is the initial data for `todos` set? It is better if you can provide where you supply data to `todos`

Comment: i edited the post with the code, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
   const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos)
   localStorage.setItem("todos", stringifyTodos);
 }, [todos]);

 useEffect(() => {
   const storedTodos = localStorage.getItem("todos")
   const items = JSON.parse(storedTodos);
   if (items) {
     setTodos(items);
   }
 }, []);
```

Try this way I think it will work.

Comment: still not worked

Comment: @MohammedAzzab I have changed my code a little. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed the problem by initializing the `todos` state by `getItem()`
like this :

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<todosObj[]>(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos") || "") || []
  );
```

If someone knows the reason why it wasn't working please tell me.